# How can I read a packet capture file from a Cisco RV 120W?

Tags: cisco, packet-capture, packet-analyzer

What program should I use?

(the file is generated on RV 120W under Diagnostics section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have one to test with, but other Cisco products write out to standard PCAP formatting.

Try Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org) - its free.